# How to create Navigation using ToolBar button

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller, uitoolbar

I have created a Toolbar button and given action() to navigate to  other ViewController.But the code is not working for Navigation.And not  able to assign a image to the button.How can i solve this?

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
[super viewDidLoad];
[self.navigationController setToolbarHidden:NO];
UIToolbar *toolbar = [[UIToolbar alloc] init];
toolbar.frame = CGRectMake(0, 418, 320, 44);
[self.view addSubview:toolbar];
[toolbar release];
UIBarButtonItem *customItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"update"  style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered  target:self action:@selector(updateAddress:)];    
NSMutableArray *toolbarItems = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:customItem,  nil];    
[toolbar setItems:toolbarItems animated:NO];
}    

-(void)updateAddress{
DisplayMapViewController *updateView=[[DisplayMapViewController alloc]init];
UINavigationController *navi=[[UINavigationController alloc]initWithRootViewController:updateView];
[self.navigationController popToViewController:navi animated:YES];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

First you should set the selector right, you should take out the `:` from the selector because you don't have parameters for the `updateAddress` method

should be like this

```
UIBarButtonItem *customItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"update"  style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered  target:self action:@selector(updateAddress)];
```

Then You need to initialize the `DisplayMapViewController` with its NibName

```
DisplayMapViewController *updateView=[[DisplayMapViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"DisplayMapViewController" bundle:nil];
```

and then just pop to the view you are intended to.

```
[self.navigationController popToViewController:updateView animated:YES];
```

if you have already rootViewController then you could just `popToRootViewController`